# Set value = value +1 in bookshelf.js

Tags: mysql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

just wanted to ask, how do i update a value in my mysql DB + 1 using bookshelf.js?

as example:
`Update table set value = value +1 where x = y ... ;`

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what exactly was the problem?

Comment: im using this:
`await Wallet.forge(row).save({balance: balance + 1}, {patch:true})` i just dont know how to tell bookshelf to update it with +1. yeah i can retrieve the balance before that with a select query, but since its async it could happen that it selects the same value twice for the same user if he clicks twice before updating it. thats why i want it into one query. this doesnt work because balance is not defined, using 'balance + 1' as a string also doesnt work here

Comment: solved the problem:
`await table.query().where('id', id).decrement('value', value)`

Comment: You can self-answer your question, so this advise is here for the next person looking for a way to do this.

Comment: `.decrement()` does the exact opposite of what you want. You should use `.increment()` instead.

Comment: yes thanks, didnt think while i was writing the command i sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved the problem: `await table.query().where('id', id).increment('value', value)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also if you want to use it within transation open in the bookshelf way, just call transacting function after query : `new Model().query().transacting(t).where('id', id).increment('value', value)`, and bookshelf will auto commit or rollback on Promise resolving or failing.