# Strapi update same field increment

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have a field called `count` and I want to update the field by a certain amount. Is it possible to do in Strapi without first getting the value of the field?

Something like this:

```
var myRating = 4;

strapi.query('post').update(
  { id: 6 },
  {
    rating: post.rating + myRating,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const result = await strapi
          .query("name of the table")
          .model.query((qb) => {
            qb.where("id", id);
            qb.increment("field", value);
          })

      .fetch();
```

I used this and it worked.

Anybody who is looking into this might want want to check these

1. https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/queries.html#custom-queries
2. [Set value = value +1 in bookshelf.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003758/set-value-value-1-in-bookshelf-js)
3. [Bookshelf.js - Nested relations while querying with andWhere()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243138/bookshelf-js-nested-relations-while-querying-with-andwhere)

Answer (score 1):

By default, you will not be able to do that with queries provide by Strapi.
But you can do it via a native SQL query.

Here is a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973380/sql-how-to-increase-or-decrease-one-for-a-int-column-in-one-command) that answer about the request to do.

Then in Strapi you will have to get [Knex to execute the query](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-raw).

To do so you will have to use `strapi.connections.default`. It give you the Knex instance.

Comment: What about using NoSQL databases?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked before Strapi 4 even existed but here's the answer for Strapi 4 using MySQL that I couldn't find any where.

You can access Knex functions through strapi.db.connection. This what worked for me:

```
let result = await strapi.db.connection('posts')
                .where({id: ctx.params.id})
                .increment('likes', 1)
                .increment('points', 2);
```

I wanted to add `.returning('likes')` but it's not supported by MySQL so it was ignored. It didn't throw any error, just a warning.

Previously with Strapi 3 I used MongoDB and that's what worked for me:

```
let post = await strapi.query('post').update(
                { id: ctx.params.id },
                {
                    $inc: {likes: 1, points: 2}
                }
            );
```